# how your send input through your microphone

Tags: input, artificial-intelligence

I am creating  a Virtual Intelligence but I was wondering what code would I write to get voice inpiut from microphone. And what will be the best language to write a V.I in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has done it already, you can work on top of that. Search it on google whatever you are looking for.

**Here is a link which might be of some use to you**

http://meta-guide.com/software-meta-guide/100-best-github-google-voice/

Comment: I mean how do I implement it in my program

Comment: you are dealing with artificial intelligence stuff, you gotta study that stuff, and understand those stuff....get down some projects from github and try running....and read through the code and understand it...it's gonna take some time to understand. I am not yet into ai , maybe next year!

Comment: Please can you give me a link

Comment: Well to learn ai, you should know programming a bit to understand stuff: https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS223A    ,  https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp  , https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS229

Comment: I do know programming but not a pro

Comment: it seems you are interested in ai, just follow those three courses, It'll help you in others ways too...